# HTML, CSS: Arrow shaped div block with text inside (verticle-align should be middle)

Tags: html, css

I guess I may be missing something really simple. I wanted to create something like below:

[image]

Here's what I've tried following the answer from one of the ques on StackOverflow, but I can't that ques again.

```css
.blockHead:after {
  color:#4D81BF;
  border-left: 20px solid;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;

}
.blockHead {
  background-color:#4D81BF;
  /*width: 150px; */
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.blocktext{
 color:white;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding-left:10px;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:11;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockHead"><span class="blocktext">ABC Team</span></div>
```

The prob is that the text appears right at the top of the div. I want it middle aligned in reference to the Div block.

Please, any help on this would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Give `display:block` to span and line-height equal to div height

Comment: use **line-height** property with equivalent value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just a matter of setting the `line-height` to be the same as the `height`

Also, you should align the arrow head to the top.

```
.blockHead {
  background-color: #4D81BF;
  /*width: 150px; */
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.blockHead:after {
  color: #4D81BF;
  border-left: 20px solid;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top:0
  }
```

```css
.blockHead:after {
  color: #4D81BF;
  border-left: 20px solid;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 0;
}
.blockHead {
  background-color: #4D81BF;
  /*width: 150px; */
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.blocktext {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 11;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockHead"><span class="blocktext">ABC Team</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Wrong element selected. Use in `blocktext`

Comment: In a small screen view (the default width of the snippet), the arrow at the right end seems to collapse itself, the text is right aligned in the middle by the way. **fixed**

Comment: Thanks man. I was all differnet things except for this. I'm still trying learn and instant help like these really push me to learn more and more. Thanks again.

Comment: @Bikas. Both work. Even if I keep it in blocktext or blockHead. Thanks!

Comment: how can I wrap large text as arrow becomes big otherwise ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `line-height` and `vertical-align` on the `span` element.

```css
.blockHead:after {
  color:#4D81BF;
  border-left: 20px solid;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;

}
.blockHead {
  background-color:#4D81BF;
  /*width: 150px; */
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.blocktext{
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding-left:10px;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:11;
  line-height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockHead"><span class="blocktext">ABC Team</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Chick this out, If I am not wrong then you need this? [click](http://jsfiddle.net/hoas724a/3/) 
Just give `line-height` to `.blocktext`

**Or**

You can also give `vertical-align:middle`

Answer (score 0):

This important parts of the following code are the last 3 rules on `.blockHead` which are `display: flex`, `justify-content: center` (I assumed you wanted to center horizontally as well) and `align-items: center`.

```
<style>
  .blockHead:after {
    color: #4D81BF;
    border-left: 20px solid;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
  }
    .blockHead {
    background-color: #4D81BF;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center;
    /* align vertical */
  }

  .blocktext {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11;
  }
</style>
<div class="blockHead">
  <span class="blocktext">
    ABC Team
  </span>
</div>
```

The link is a screenshot of what the above code renders.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X9hP.jpg

This solution will scale if you want to add multiple lines of text to the buttons and if you want to change sizes.

Answer (score 0):

If any one interested in using the pointer in other direction

Shape CSS Source:https://sharkcoder.com/visual/shapes

```css
.blockHead:after {
  color: #4D81BF;
  /*border-left: 20px solid;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;*/
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid #32557f;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
}

.blockHead {
  background-color: #4D81BF;
  /* width: 150px;*/
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
/* align horizontal */
align-items: center;
/* align vertical */
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.blocktext {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 11;
  line-height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockHead"><span class="blocktext">ABC Team</span></div>
```